# IE7 Issue: text won't wrap around floated div

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css-float

I cannot get paragraphs of text to wrap around a floated:left div on IE7 on this page: http://www.guidetoonlineschools.com/online-reviews/ashford-university (look under "Most Recent Reviews")

Both the floated div and the paragraphs are within a div that is not floated. I have tried giving the floated div both a width in pixels and percentages.

Here is the HTML (non-essential parts indicated with an ellipsis:

```
    <div class="review_body">
        <div class="reviews_3d_box">
             <div class="review_dots"><table>...</table></div>
        </div>
        <div class="review_content">
             <p>...</p><p>...</p>
         </div>
         <div>...</div>
    </div>
```

.reviews_3d_box is the floated div with this CSS:

```
{padding-left: 10px;
 margin: 0 15px 0 -25px;
 background: url(/assets/images/graphics/reviews_corner.gif) no-repeat 0 6px;
 width: 45%;
 float: left;}
```

The paragraphs in .review_content wrap around this floated div in every browser but IE 7.

Can anyone advise what the problem might be? Thanks!

Comment: This link seems like it might help you: http://css-class.com/articles/explorer/floats/floatandcleartest1.htm
It seems IE7 is notorious for not displaying CSS correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `review_content` element has `min-height: 110px` which triggers `hasLayout` for this element in IE7.

Comment: Marat, are you aware of a workaround? I gave review_content a min-height because, since these are user generated reviews and are of variable length, I need to make sure that if the content is too short, the floated div wont "crash into" the div below the content. Thanks!

Comment: Just use clearing. It can be either `clear: both` for `.was_helpful` element or (better) [self-clearing](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) for a new wrapper (nonexistent currently) that would contain both `.reviews_3d_box` and `.review_content` elements. `min-height` is not quite bullet-proof since height of floating block (as well as any text block) can vary depending on font-size, OS settings, browser settings, available fonts, etc.